# How to retrieve data from Quickbooks using PHP?

Tags: quickbooks

I want to retrieve data (i.e  rental truck income & apartment income) from Quickbooks and want to store in my local MYSQL database using PHP, Please help me, I am not getting what I do.

Thanks,
Shama Kausar

Answer (score 2):

First, read up on the [QuickBooks Web Connector](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector). You can download it [from Intuit's website](http://marketplace.intuit.com/webconnector/).

Then, go grab the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/) (disclaimer: I'm the author of the DevKit). Unzip and look at this file:

- docs/example_web_connector_import.php

Follow our [QuickBooks and PHP Quick-Start guide](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start) except when it says to use docs/example_web_connector.php, substitute in docs/example_web_connector_import.php instead.

That will get you importing customers/items/a bit of other stuff from QuickBooks, into your MySQL database.

QuickBooks doesn't really have any concept of "rental truck income & apartment income", so you'll have to find out specifically what you want out of QuickBooks. Are those Accounts in your Chart of Accounts? Are they Invoices? Received Payments?

Once you know specifically what types of objects you want, you can use the [QuickBooks OSR](http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html) (use the "Select Message" drop-down at the top of the screen, and choose the "XML Ops" tab) to find out what XML you need to send to QuickBooks to get back the data you're looking for. It should then be trivial to modify the script to pull that data instead of the data that it pulls by default.